# Changing Redactor settings doesn't work

Tags: redactor

I'm trying to change Redactor's settings by editing `craft/config/Standard.json` (and `Simple.json`) but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all. I logged out, emptied Craft's and browser cache and still don't see any changes.

Is this feature broken in the current Craft version or am I missing something? I edit the file by removing/adding buttons, like this:

```
{
    "buttons": ["html","formatting","bold",],"plugins":["fullscreen","video"],
    "toolbarFixed": true
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you select that config file in your Richtext field's settings?

Comment: that was it! Is there a way to change the default docs instead of going to all blocks and setting this manually?

Comment: I don't think so, do you have that many Richtext fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select that config file you edited in your Richtext field's settings. See the settings options for ["Rich Text fields"](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/rich-text-fields#redactor-configs) in the Craft Docs.